# What programming Shapr3D ipad app is written in?

Tags: ipad, cad

What programming Shapr3D ipad app is written in?

I doubt it would be in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Previous versions of Shapr3D relied on C++ framework [Open CASCADE Technology](https://dev.opencascade.org/), and latest versions use Parasolid API (Parasolid kernel become available on iOS much later than open-source OCCT), which is referred as C-callable in some references. So I would guess that many portions of application should be written in **C++**.

The bindings to UIKit, however, should be written in either **Objective-C/C++** or **Swift**, as Apple left no other choice to developers. The latter one requires more efforts for incorporating C++ code and I don't know if Swift gives any solid advantages over Objective-C++ for GUI development to make these extra efforts worthwhile.

These are just my guesses for a closed-source application.
I think that asking the same question on application's forum would have more chances to get reliable answer (although I barely see any use of such knowledge).